# PHP variable value to NOT update MySQL table field?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm updating a MySQL table with posted PHP data.
I first gather the posted data, and put them in appropriate variables. Together with the necessary if/else checks.

Then, I only have to write my query once.

But now I have an if/else to check wether to update a specific field or not. How can I store a **"do-not-update" value** inside the corresponding variable?

Because otherwise I have to put an if/else check around the whole query, just for one field.

I just want to be as efficient as possible. :)

My query is as follows:

```
$updateTable = mysql_query("UPDATE myTable SET field1 = '$field1', field2 = '$field2'");
```

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without seeing your code.

Comment: You don't really have to see my code for this.. I just want to store some sort of string in a variable that MySQL recognizes as a "do-not-update" value, if that's even possible.

Comment: would the specific field never be updated? or only for that particular record?

Comment: @dzogchen Only for a particular record.

Comment: If you can alter the table, add a field for storing data about altering the field, and use that.   Otherwise you end up putting some "code" into the field - which alters it right there.  you might be better served dealing with this in the if / else portion of things, and using the if / else to determine whether to include the field in the update query...

Comment: That's what I want to avoid, having another line of query code. Can't this be done efficiently with just one variable?

Comment: You could set `field1=field1`, but that's a bit nasty. Just build the query dynamically.

Comment: Can you explain why that's nasty? And I can't store the field name in a boolean field, right?

Comment: Just came across this question.. @fishbaitfood, how reliable has the accepted answer worked for you so far? I'm wondering if the implementation is too ghetto, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wherever you are get $_POST into variables, do this,

```
 if( $field2 === 'xyz' ) { //if value is 'xyz', do not update
     $sql = ''; 
  } else 
      $sql = ", field2 = '$field2'";
```

Then in the query,

```
   $updateTable = mysql_query("UPDATE myTable SET field1 = '$field1' $sql");
```

**Edit:** if using 1/0 (true or false),

```
   if( $field2 == true ) { //if value is true, do not update
     $sql = ''; 
  } else 
      $sql = ", field2 = '$field2'";
```

Comment: you mean if `$field2 = true/false` ?

Comment: I use 1/0, but yes. If I pass a '' value, my field will still update to the opposite boolean.

Comment: That seems like an appropriate, simple solution. :) Thanks!

Comment: @fishbaitfood  - this should work - you aren't passing an empty value, since you aren't even referencing the field in the query

Comment: Indeed, I should've come up with this myself!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to build up your query, storing it in a PHP string, for example:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `table` SET ";
if ($_POST['foo']!=='') {
  $sql .= " `foo`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['foo'])."',";
}
if ($_POST['bar']!=='') {
  $sql .= " `bar`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bar'])."',";
}
$sql = rtrim($sql,',');
$sql .= " WHERE `id`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'])."'"
```

Then execute your string as the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether the field should be updated, you can do one of two things:

1) Specify a criteria that ensures `field1` and `field2` are only updated if the rows match the criteria. If the criteria does not match, the record will not be updated. This is the most common way.

```
UPDATE myTable ...
WHERE criteria1 = 1 AND criteria2 = 'Red'
```

2) Run a query before the `UPDATE` to see whether to perform an update.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking for, but perhaps this answers your question:

```
$updateTable = mysql_query("
UPDATE myTable SET
    field1 = IF('$field1'>'','$field1', field1),
    field2 = IF('$field2'>'','$field2', field2)
");
```

Of course, you are opening yourself up to SQL injection with the code, as written.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have gathered the fields to update in an array `$fields` like this :

```
array (
'filed1' => 'value' ,
'field2' => ''value
)
```

Now you need to generate the query, you can do this by looping in the array:

```
    $sql = "UPDATE mytable ";
$sql .= $fields ? "SET " : "" ;
    foreach ($fields as $key=>$value) {
    $sql.= $value ? "$key = '$value' , " : '' ;
    }
    //you need to omit the trailing ','
$sql[strlen($sql) -1 ] = "";
```

Tips :
Do sanitize all user input using [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or something better than that.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks! And I do use mysql_real_escape_string() :)